# $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)$ is a Banach algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm studying different analytic spaces and found a [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_space). The following quote from the article isn't too clear why it is the case.

> the space $\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)$ is a Banach algebra, with respect to the norm $\|f\|_{\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)} := \|f\|_{H^\infty(\Omega)} + \mathcal{D}(f)^{1/2} \; \; \; \; \; (f \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega))$.

Can somebody explain why this space is in fact an algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows immediately from the Minkowski integral inequality:

$\mathcal{D}(fg)^{1/2}=(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\Omega}|f'g+fg'|^2dA)^{1/2} \le (\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\Omega}|f'g|^2dA)^{1/2}+(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\Omega}|fg'|^2dA)^{1/2} \le \mathcal{D}(f)^{1/2}||g||_{\infty}+\mathcal{D}(g)^{1/2}||f||_{\infty} < \infty$

if both $f,g \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)$

Since $||fg||_{\infty} \le ||f||_{\infty}||g||_{\infty}$ we get that $\|fg\|_{\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)} \le \|f\|_{\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)}\|g\|_{\mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)} <\infty $

(Note that it is not generally true that if $f \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega), g \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega) \cap H^\infty(\Omega)$ we necessarily have $fg \in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$)

Comment: I now understand how the norm is found. Forgive me if it's too obvious, but how does this show that $\mathcal{D}$ itself is a Banach algebra?

Comment: the norm satisfies the required algebraic inequality $||fg|| \le ||f||||g||$ and both $D(f), ||.||_{\infty}$ are complete (here, as usual, $D(f)$ is only a seminorm actually as $D(f+c)=D(f)$ but like with the Dirichlet definition that doesn't really matter as we add a "real" norm to it)  so the norm is complete (if a sequence is Cauchy in the sum of the two norms, is Cauchy in each norm etc)